# Error starting tomcat7.service in arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, apache-httpd, tomcat

The os is running is Arch Linux x86-64. I'm trying to start `tomcat7.service` via `systemctl start tomcat7.service`, but it throws a error message:

```
Job for tomcat7.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tomcat7.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I execute `systemctl status tomcat7.service`, it shows this message:

```
● tomcat7.service - Tomcat 7 servlet container
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tomcat7.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-04-02 04:28:40 CEST; 2min 40s ago
  Process: 2979 ExecStop=/usr/bin/jsvc -pidfile /var/run/tomcat7.pid -stop org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap (code=exited, status=255)
   Process: 2972 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jsvc -Dcatalina.home=${CATALINA_HOME} -Dcatalina.base=${CATALINA_BASE} -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp/tomcat7/temp -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.>
 Main PID: 2977

abr 02 04:28:40 carlos-pc systemd[1]: Starting Tomcat 7 servlet container...
abr 02 04:28:40 carlos-pc jsvc[2972]: Cannot find any VM in Java Home /usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime
abr 02 04:28:40 carlos-pc systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/tomcat7.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
abr 02 04:28:40 carlos-pc systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Supervising process 2977 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
abr 02 04:28:40 carlos-pc jsvc.exec[2976]: 2018-04-02 04:28:40 2977 jsvc.exec error: Cannot find any VM in Java Home /usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime
                                       2018-04-02 04:28:40 2977 jsvc.exec error: Cannot locate JVM library file
abr 02 04:28:40 carlos-pc systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
abr 02 04:28:40 carlos-pc systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Killing process 2977 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
abr 02 04:28:40 carlos-pc systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Killing process 2977 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
abr 02 04:28:40 carlos-pc systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
abr 02 04:28:40 carlos-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Tomcat 7 servlet container.
```

If I make `ls /usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime` to check if I have a Java environment, it shows:

```
bin  conf  demo  include  jmods  legal  lib  man  release
```

So, directory exists.

What could be happening? Thank you

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tomcat#Using_Tomcat_with_a_different_JRE.2FJDK

Comment: It gives the same error, but, instead of show `/usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime`, it shows `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk` (as excepted)

Comment: Are you sure you have a Java installed in your Arch Linux? Check [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java#Installation) for more instructions. If you use the command `archlinux-java status`, does it list one or more versions of Java installed?

Comment: I think so. I can run and compile java programas via java and javac respectively. When I execute `archlinux-java status`, it is only show one version: `java-9-openjdk (default)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set java-8 or earlier as your default java version to work with tomcat on archlinux. Follow the arch wiki guide to get the correct version installed. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java#Officially_supported_packages

To do that run:

```
sudo archlinux-java set java-8-openjdk
```

Comment: I tried with java 8 and java 7

Comment: Does the output of `journalctl -xe` change after trying to restart `systemctl start tomcat<version#>.service` ?

Comment: No. Also, I tried to stop and star the service again

Comment: I had the same problem, with tomcat8 on arch, and setting the default to java-8 fixed the problem for me. If you have the option to migrate to tomcat8, that may solve your problem.

Comment: At first time, I was working with tomcat8